# UIPickerView selectRow inComponent not working

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have been working on a multi-component picker and I wanted to set the defaults for the various components. The code looks like the following.

```
#import "MathTablesSelectVC.h"

@interface MathTablesSelectVC ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *problemDifficultyTypeTable;

@property NSArray *problemDifficulties;
@property NSArray *problemTypes;
@property NSArray *problemTables;

@end

@implementation MathTablesSelectVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"0");
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"1");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _problemDifficulties = @[@"Practice", @"Slow", @"Normal", @"Fast"];
    _problemTypes = @[@"Addition", @"Subtraction", @"Multiplication", @"Division", @"Remainders"];
    _problemTables = @[@" 0's", @" 1's", @" 2's", @" 3's", @" 4's", @" 5's", @" 6's", @" 7's", @" 8's", @" 9's", @"10's", @"11's", @"12's", @"All"];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"2");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_problemDifficultyTypeTable selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [_problemDifficultyTypeTable selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:NO];
    [_problemDifficultyTypeTable selectRow:1 inComponent:2 animated:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    NSLog(@"3");

    return 3;
}

-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component     {
    NSLog(@"4");
    if(component == 0) {
        return 150.0;
    } else if(component == 1) {
        return 300.0;
    } else {
        return 75.0;
    }
}

-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"5");
    return 60.0;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"6");
    if(component == 0) {
        return [_problemDifficulties count];
    } else if(component == 1) {
        return [_problemTypes count];
    } else {
        return [_problemTables count];
    }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"7");
    if(component == 0) {
        return [_problemDifficulties objectAtIndex:row];
    } else if(component == 1) {
        return [_problemTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
        return [_problemTables objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"8");
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"9");
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"10");
}

@end
```

Now this all worked nicely for a while and then it stopped working :(

Answer (score 0):

I then spent the next several hours working out what I'd done wrong.

The answer I stuffed things up when I did some refactoring. I managed to kill the connection between the storyboard and the IBOutlet. Now the nice small, very small, little circle was still there next to the @property it just no longer had a dot in it. As soon as I re-established the connection things started behaving again.

You'll also note a whole bunch of NSLog's and this seems to be the order things are first called in. We get several repeats of some of the numbers as we cycle through the components.

The other thing I broke although I picked that up pretty much straight away were the delegation connections.

Comment: If you are going to give something a downvote it might be nice if you explained why.